# VBA IF statement with multiple conditions

Tags: vba, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have got an IF statement that looks like that:

```
If i=1 or i=3 or i=7 or i=9 or i=10 or i>=15 and i<=20 then
   'Do sth.
End If
```

My question is: Can I make these conditions easier (can I summarize them)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can use select case:

```
Select Case i
    Case 1,3,7,9,10, 15 to 20
        'Do sth.
End Select
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Nice job with the `15 to 20` as well

Answer (score 1):

You could use Select Case.  It would look something like this...

```
Sub test()
    Select Case i
        Case 1, 3, 7, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
            'do something
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But there is nothing like i={1,3,7,9,10,15 to 20} to make the condition more easy?

Comment: @T.P. you can load the whole into an array and loop the array, but that is significantly more code and time than just using a select case, which in this case will be the easiest and quickest.